# How can I make the leading text in my expansionTile line up with the leading text in its child?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

So I'm currently trying to make the dashes in my expansionTiles line up. (Btw if you could find a better way of connecting expansionTiles with dashes, please let me know).

[This is what the app looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bklvk.png)

As you can see, the child is off by a little bit. I'm currently using an expansionTile and then an appBar for its child.

```
return ExpansionTile(
      onExpansionChanged: (value) => isExpanded,
      title: Text(curStopList[index % curStopList.length][0]),
      // subtitle: Text('Next Arrival: ' +
      //     _getTimeIndex(shuttleTimeLists[idx]).toString()),
      leading: index == 0
          ? Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  height: 15,
                  width: 15,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      border:
                          Border.all(width: .5, color: Colors.greenAccent)),
                ),
                Dash(
                    direction: Axis.vertical,
                    length: 20,
                    dashLength: 5,
                    dashColor: Colors.grey),
              ],
            )
          : Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Dash(
                    direction: Axis.vertical,
                    length: 20,
                    dashLength: 5,
                    dashColor: Colors.grey),
                Container(
                  height: 15,
                  width: 15,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      border:
                          Border.all(width: .5, color: Colors.greenAccent)),
                ),
                Dash(
                    direction: Axis.vertical,
                    length: 20,
                    dashLength: 5,
                    dashColor: Colors.grey),
              ],
            ),
      trailing:
          isExpanded ? Text('Show Arrivals +') : Text('Hide Arrivals -'),
      children: [
        AppBar(
          titleSpacing: 1,
          leading: Dash(
              direction: Axis.vertical,
              length: 55,
              dashLength: 5,
              dashColor: Colors.grey),
        )
      ],
    );
```

[UPDATE: This is with debugPaintSiuzeEnabled(Looks really bright so idk if u can see things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McLMD.png)

[UPDATE 2: Space between the tiles?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVZor.png)

Comment: set `debugPaintSizeEnabled = true` and post the screenshot again

Comment: I added 'debugPaintSizeEnabled = true', it looks really bright though, so idk if u can see things

Comment: Thank you very much for this response, it was very helpful. But I now have another problem where if I add a subtitle, there is a gap between the tiles. I put the screenshot in update 2. Should I be editing the expansion tile flutter file now?

Comment: check `material/expansion_tile.dart`  file, it has `_buildChildren()` method which returns a `Container` with a border decoration - this is a "gap" you see between the tiles, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ce40de69b7/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expansion_tile.dart#L219

Comment: Should I be getting rid of the border decoration? because when I do, nothing happens. I'm using a pixel 3a

Comment: *"because when I do, nothing happens"* - what you do? i dont understand

Comment: I got rid of the border decoration in expansion_tile.dart. I thought this caused the expansion tile to have extra space between tiles. When I got rid of it, everything in my app stayed the same and the gap was still there. I was wondering what I should be doing to this border decoration to get rid of the gap

Comment: do not modify `expansion_tile.dart` directly - instead copy it to your project and remove `decoration:` part - i did it and now there is no gap

Comment: I made a copy and deleted the decoration part, but unfortunately the gaps were still there. Even with subtitles on ur expansion tile, there were still no gaps? This is what my expansiontile looks like -> https://imgur.com/rCOZDgV.

Comment: seems you posted wrong img as it is not your original list of bus? stops

Comment: Oh no, I meant that was the custom expansion tile file with the decoration deleted. When I use that, the gaps between tile is still there when subtitles get added. Without subtitles, expansion tile is fine with no gaps

Comment: seems it's hardcoded in `ListTile`